# group.facet = true in sol query 6.6

Tags: solr

In the solr query `group.facet = true` and `facet.range` is used. After executing the query in solr, I get the following error:

> Unexpected docvalues type NUMERIC for field '' (expected=SORTED). Re-index with correct docvalues type.

If I remove `group.facet = false` or remove it the query works

Comment: How is defined the facetted field in schema.xml ?